# ubiquity customization

Tags: ubiquity

I installed ubiquity:

```
sudo apt-get install ubiquity ubiquity-casper ubiquity-slideshow-ubuntu ubiquity-frontend-gtk
```

and I made some modifications to it:

- changed the images to match my company
- added new slides
- etc....

Everything looks good, but now how can I put it back into the installer?

Do I need to re-compile? Use lz? Something else?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No.  You don't need to recompile these HTML files or archive them.

When you rebuild the iso, this folder will automatically be used for the installation.

Just make sure the images you will use are not bigger (width x height) than the originals;  otherwise you will have weird results.