# How to change the UI of Ubuntu server during the installation process?

Tags: server

I want to change the appearance of Ubuntu server during the installation process, Ubuntu server 16.04 installation is text based. I want to change to Graphical install with custom picture, make it looks better. how to change it?

Comment: What you are asking is NOT easy. You must use the Desktop installer (not the Server installer), because that's the graphical installer. Then you must learn how to edit the list of packages so it installs Ubuntu Server instead of a Desktop. Then you must learn how to edit the graphics. Finally, you must learn how to restore the installer to squashfs and make it bootable again. If this question is a fair indication of your skills and familiarity with Ubuntu, the project may take you several days, perhaps a full week, perhaps longer.

Comment: If I use the Desktop installer, how to change?

Comment: Look up how to use a Preseed file.

Comment: I already use the preseed file, but it seems to have nothing to do with the appearance of installation process.

Comment: Oh, then see https://askubuntu.com/questions/84607/ubiquity-customization